# Cannot use tailwind class text manipulation and custom animation from components imported into app/page.jsx

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

The Problem is class `font-bold text-4xl, animate-waving-hand` and other text manipulation classes such as `leadinf-[1.8] md:leading-loose`. do not work in the Home component. but when adding the classname to the HomePage component in app/page.jsx the class is active and works. the code is like this

**app/page.jsx**

```
import Home from "@/modules/home"
export default async function HomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Home className="font-bold text-4xl animate-waving-hand" />
      <div>
        <div className='flex gap-2 font-bold text-4xl'>
          <h1> Hi, I&apos;m Alil</h1>
          <div className="ml-1 animate-waving-hand"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

but when using components like the code I expect this to not work

this is the **app/page.jsx code**

```
import Home from "@/modules/home/components/Home.jsx"
export default async function HomePage() {
  return (
    <>
      <Home />
    </>
  )
}
```

this is **modules/home/index.js**

```
import Home from "./components/Home";
export default Home
```

and this is **modules/home/components/Home.jsx**

```
import Link from "next/link"
import { TbCoffee } from 'react-icons/tb'
export default function Home() {
  return (
    <>
      <div>
        <div className='flex gap-2 font-bold text-4xl'>
          <h1> Hi, I&apos;m Alil</h1>
          <div className="ml-1 animate-waving-hand"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

what's wrong with the code? am very confused and have spent 15 hours trying to fix it. this is the github repo of my project
https://github.com/allail-qadrillah/Portofolio/blob/master/app/page.jsx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you need to setup the `content` array in `tailwind.config.js` by adding modules directory:

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {

  //...

  content: [
    './pages/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    './components/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    './app/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    './src/**/*.{js,jsx}',
    './modules/**/*.{js,jsx}' // <-- add this
    ],

    //...
}
```

This is an array that specifies the files to be analyzed.

Comment: Correct! In order for Tailwind to generate all of the CSS you need, it needs to know about every single file in your project that contains any Tailwind class names. [more info](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/content-configuration#configuring-source-paths)

Comment: yeah. am forgot to add folder modules to tailwind configuration. thanks broh